# Filtering an array into 3 separate arrays

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, filter

I have a very large array that I am trying to split into three separate arrays in python, such every i = 1+3(n-i), i = 2 +3(n-1), and i%3==0 get sorted into three different arrays. Any help would be appreciated.

```
for i in range(num_steps):
    xyz0 = np.array([1.0,1,1])
    xyz[] = fsolve(Neuro, xyz0, bvals)
    re[i] =xyz[1+3(i-1)]
    rp[i] = xyz[2+3(i-1)]
        for i%3 == 0
            rs[i] = xyz[i]
```

this code makes no sense but it's an idea

Comment: Where is your code? Have you tried using conditions like `if i%3==0:`?

Comment: @not_speshal that one I've used but for the two others I have no idea what to do

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: How about `if i%3==1` etc.?

Comment: [I’m stuck](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/), without specifics, and without your applicable research, is an issue for a tutor in problem analysis or specification.  It’s not focused enough for Stack Overflow.  Using %3 is the straightforward solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Python's extended slicing syntax. Calling `l[n::3]` will return the items of `l` starting from index `n`, stepping over `3` each time. Below is an example for what you requested:

```py
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

first  = list[0::3]
middle = list[1::3]
last   = list[2::3]
```

Printing these gives the desired outputs:

```py
>>> print(first)
[1, 4, 7]
>>> print(middle)
[2, 5, 8]
>>> print(last)
[3, 6]
```